# PXE Network autoconfiguration failed

Tags: 14.04, networking, dhcp, pxe

When I use PXE to install ubuntu14.04.5 server, it stopped at network configuration. I can fixed the problem by set the network manually. However, I want to find a solution to resolve the problem without my manual help.

Here is the problem picture:

[image]

Comment: Is there an issue with network connectivity? Are you sure DHCP is enabled on  your network?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure my DHCP service is working correctly. If I press Alt+F2 ,at the command shell,  type 'ifconfig', I can see the IP address allocated by DHCP.

Comment: And, if my dhcp service is disabled,  it will not start installing, we can't see the error report.

Comment: Have you tried `cat /var/log/syslog` as per this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44379

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the `cat /var/log/syslog | grep 67`, and I did sure my dhcp server is working.